# Running Script on Shutdown using Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, powershell

Is there any way to execute a Batch- or PowerShell-Script on shutdown using Windows 8 without disabling FastBoot?

I know you can add a script using "gpedit.msc", but I found that Windows 8 won't execute the shutdown script as long as FastBoot is enabled.

Having to deploy the script in an enterprise I don't wanna add shutdown command at the end of the script and tell some dozens people to shutdown the PC via the script.

Comment: May you can do something along the lines of this user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782944/run-a-batch-file-on-windows-7-shutdown-before-closing-programs-preferrably-on-p who wanted to shutdown his Virtual machine on Windows shutdown. Note that that posts references others too.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but i cant find any solution in this post. The problem is, that Windows won't execute any scripts i added to be executed on shutdown via "gpedit.msc". It works if i use "shutdown -s" or restart the pc

Comment: Ah, I misread that post - he is also using a script.

Comment: Ok I did some research again. It appears, that it is no longer possible with Win8 to execute a script on shutdown using gpedit. I was told, that a possible solution would be to create a scheduled task and link this to an event, that occurs on shutdown, yet i didn´t try this one

Comment: Did that work? :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a wmi event watcher on `Win32_ComputerShutdownEvent`, run it silently in the background from your logon script.  It will wait all-day for the shutdown command.  Upon event, send the `"shutdown -a"` and call your script.

Answer (score 0):

I found this at [KIOSKEA](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3358-execute-a-script-a-startup-and-shutdown)(work below) also check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/377387/how-to-add-a-shutdown-script-not-by-using-gpedit-msc-or-active-directory) out.

Open notepad and copy the code below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts]    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown]    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup]    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup\0]    
"GPO-ID"="LocalGPO"    
"SOM-ID"="Local"    
"FileSysPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine"    
"DisplayName"="Stratégie de groupe locale"    
"GPOName"="Stratégie de groupe locale"    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0]    
"GPO-ID"="LocalGPO"    
"SOM-ID"="Local"    
"FileSysPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine"    
"DisplayName"="Stratégie de groupe locale"    
"GPOName"="Stratégie de groupe locale"    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup\0\0]    
"Script"="C:\\script1.bat"    
"Parameters"=""    
"ExecTime"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Once you understand the code, you can adapt it to suit your needs by changing some of the variables.

`C:\\script.bat` represents the path to your script on the hard disk.
`0` represents the number of the script in case you have several scripts to run.
`Startup` is the time of execution of the script (at startup is Startup and shutdown is Shutdown)

It is possible to add multiple scripts:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Startup\0\0]    
"Script"="C:\\script1.bat"    
"Parameters"=""    
"ExecTime"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

It is also possible to specify parameters for the execution of this script by changing the Parameters field.

Finally, save this text file:

- Go to File > Save
- Give it a name ending with .reg
- Select All files in the list box File Type
- Save the file to the desired location and double click on this file